# ImportError: No module named exiftool

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, exiftool

I am running the exiftool inside a python script but it throws me this error, which i googled but no luck.

**What i have done so far:**
Installed the exiftool on mac using the command:

```
brew install exiftool
```

It installs succesfully without any problems.

Set the PATH variable to exiftool:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/exiftool/10.55_1/:$PATH
```

which i have confirmed by the using the `echo $PATH` command.

Lastly, When i do `sudo pip install exiftool` , Throws me an error.

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyexiftool
>   (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pyexiftool

I am not sure, what i have missed in the steps. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/install.html#OSX

Comment: I already have checked this link before posting. Either i can install it through homebrew or download .dmg file, its the same.

Comment: I think the only thing you have missed is that there is no package named `pyexiftool` on PyPI yet. There is an [issue for this opened on github](https://github.com/smarnach/pyexiftool/issues/8), though. Meanwhile, you can install the package from github repo directly: `pip install git+https://github.com/smarnach/pyexiftool.git#egg=pyexiftool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why is not working with brew installation but i installed it manually through this link [here](http://no.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/install.html#OSX)

Then i made sure that the system recognises the exif tool command by running this command on the terminal

```
exiftool -S -Make filename.jpg
```

And then in my code i did something like this:

```
EXIFTOOL_PATH = '/usr/local/bin/exiftool'

with exiftool.ExifTool(EXIFTOOL_PATH) as et:
  the_et = et
  # Some logic
```